# How can I have a specific number of items on checkout in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am currently trying to edit a jmeter test (for eCommerce) so i would have 10% of X number of users have a specific number of 5 products in the cart ( nothing more, nothing less).

If using a While Controller, how and what should i add?

I have created a CSV file with around 20 items so it can loop through the items i have selected.

The problem is that currently the cart counting starts from 1 and stops at 5, and the checkout is not made. Before adding the While Controller, the checkout was correctly made.

Where and what should i change?

I have compared 2 tests : on the first one, the checkout is correctly made. Items are randomly added, starting with one, finishing with a random number. The checkout is made using an If controller and a throughput controller.

On the second test, having the same set up for the checkout, i have added a condition ${cartitems} == 5 before the checkout( the var is declared before). The items are still randomly added, starting with 1.

Answer (score 3):

No one will be able to help unless you share more details, few hints:

- Inspect *jmeter.log* file, in case of While Controller malfunction (i.e. bad condition) JMeter should write something there
- Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and compare request and response details for 2 scenarios:

  1. Without While Controller
  2. With While Controller

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for some hints on JMeter tests troubleshooting

Comment: I have tried with both While controller and Loop Controller. While seemed to be a bit better for this, but i don't really know how to configure it. The difference was that one test stops before checkout, the other one proceeds to checkout. I can't figure out what condition i should add to have a specific number of products in all carts and also proceed to checkout with only 3% of the users, not all.